# Module not found error while compiling MKL library with Visual Studio 2019 and windows 10

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, intel-mkl

I am facing a strange behavior of Visual Studio 2019 (v 16.5.4) while producing a python module linked against Intel MKL libraries (2020 Update 1). Any help would be appreciated !

To reproduce it : create a small python module "Project1.pyd" using VS2019 with the following lines

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <mkl.h>

void test() {
    const MKL_INT m(10);
    double test[m*m];
    cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, m, m, m, 1., test, m, test, m, 0., test, m);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(Project1, m) {
    m.def("test", &test);
}
```

This code is linked against mkl_rt.lib as added library dependancy to get cblas_dgemm defined. Then I call the module with the simple python line

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
import Project1 as p
```

leading to 'DLL load failed: Module not found'

Note that I was able to run the same code using VS2019 16.4.5 / Python 3.6.

The awful thing is that the compiler or the linker does not complain about anything : I spent three full days to identify and isolate this problem as it arised in a big C++ / python library.

Comment: Do you have the path to MKL DLLs in `PATH`?

Comment: Likely the MKL dlls are not found, or they are found but one of their dependencies are not found. In the end the solution is to set up your PATH correctly. Use https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies to load Project1.pyd to see what is missing.

Comment: yes. The linker is in Verbose mode, and show that mlk librairies are called:
1>    Recherche en cours C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2020.1.216\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib :
1>      cblas_dgemm trouvé
1>        Référencé dans Source.obj
1>        Chargé mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(cblas_dgemm_lp64.obj)

Comment: That's the linker showing it finds the import libraries. That is not the same as finding a dll at runtime.

Comment: You are right. I added to path but doesn't solve the problem. I am looking with dependancy walker to see what is happening.

Comment: Ok, dependancy has shown that the MKL libraries was not found. Adding to path solved the problem (Indeed, it seems that Intel moved MKL_CORE.dll in a different directory than the one I was expecting. Problem solved thus ! Thank you so much for your advises.

Comment: I'd suggest to either delete your question then, or post an answer yourself: that is more useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved using stijn and Evg suggestions :

1) The issue was characterized using Dependency (github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) : MKL libraries was not found - it seems that MKL run-time libraries changed directories from version 19 to 20.

2) To solve the issue, simply add to global variable PATH MKL run-time libraries (here mkl_core and mkl_intel_thread).